# remove parent span tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove both span tag using Jquery from following code
Because div is child of span it will give errors in w3validators:

```
    <td class="col-1 col-first">
    **<span>
    <span>**
    <div class="user-picture">
    <a href="/users/shoprite-mp" title="View user profile.">
    <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://locationbasedmedia.co.za/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/pictures/picture-580-1379344365.jpg" alt="Shoprite Mp's picture" title="Shoprite Mp's picture"/>
    </a>
    </div>
    **</span>
    </span>**
    </td>
```

Comment: since it is a validator error I think you will have to make the changes in markup itself not using script

Comment: You can't use scripting to fix validation errors. The HTML as delivered to the browser must be correct.

Comment: There is no valid scripting solution for your pruposes; you have to fix your html markup.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
$(".user-picture").unwrap();
$(".user-picture").unwrap();
```

Used unwrap twice as to remove both parent spans and keep the internal structure.

Comment: No need to do the DOM query twice, simply `$(".user-picture").unwrap().unwrap();` works. You're probably thinking of the unusual return value of `wrap`.

Comment: will it solve the validator problem... it will remove the span elements but the purpose of the question is to make it a valid html page

Comment: This is not working. when we click on view source on browser then it will not reflected there...

It will only reflected in firebug..

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be this:

```
$('td').click(function () {
    var content = $('.user-picture', this).detach();
    $(this).append(content);
    $('span', this).remove()l
});
```

`unwrap` works perfectly well for your scenario, but at times you want to move the .user-picture around a bit more than just 2 levels, [`detach`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) helps with that while keeping the object (including it's attributes and events) intact.

Comment: This is not working. when we click on view source on browser then it will not reflected there

Comment: Of course it will not be reflected in the view-source. NO change you ever do in JavaScript will be there because the source is not changing - only the Document Object Model (DOM). If you want to pass W3C Validation you'll have to write valid markup - you can't use JavaScript to pass that validation.